# How do you maintain make a camera move to a new position smoothy while still looking at a target?

Tags: three.js, 3d, camera, rotation, linear-algebra

In this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64172918/1675976), I asked about how one would moves a camera to a different position relative to a target. A very kind gentleman @TheJim01 provided a veery nice answer.

However, I am getting issues with this where the camera is rotated and positioned strangely after I move it.

What are the strategies to keep the camera rotated and maintaining its view of the target smoothly?

[image: threejs-camera-target]

Comment: You're probably going to have to show what you mean for this one. "Rotated and positioned strangely," doesn't give enough information. Some screenshots of what you have, possibly vs. what you want, and showing the code of how you got where you are would all be helpful.

Comment: Ok I will create a Codepen

Comment: If possible, please use a [snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do). That way all the code stays on Stack Overflow, embedded in the relevant question, and future readers don't have to worry about dead links.

Comment: Dude, @CodyBugstein, if TheJim's answer was so nice, at least give his answer an upvote, or mark it as accepted, before hitting him with a follow-up question.

Comment: Yes sorry I meant to. If you look at my history I always accept and upvote good answers! Thanks very much @TheJim01!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use any tweening library (Tween.js, GSAP) to move your camera smoothly from current position to the position atop of the sphere.

Also, use `THREE.Spherical()` to compute the final point. And don't forget to use `.makeSafe()` method.

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
}
button{
  position: absolute;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<button id="moveUp">MOVE UP</button>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/gsap@3.5.1/dist/gsap.min.js"></script>
<script type="module">
import * as THREE from "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.121.1/build/three.module.js";
import { OrbitControls } from "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.121.1/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js";

let scene = new THREE.Scene();
scene.fog = new THREE.Fog(0x000000, 6, 15);
let camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(60, innerWidth / innerHeight, 1, 100);
camera.position.set(0, 0, 10);
let renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize(innerWidth, innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

let controls = new OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
controls.maxDistance = 10;
controls.minDistance = 7;

let sphere = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.SphereBufferGeometry(4, 36, 18), new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: "aqua", wireframe: true}));
scene.add(sphere);

moveUp.addEventListener("click", onButtonClick);

let spherical = new THREE.Spherical();
let startPos = new THREE.Vector3();
let endPos = new THREE.Vector3();
let axis = new THREE.Vector3();
let tri = new THREE.Triangle();

function onButtonClick(event){
  spherical.setFromVector3(camera.position);
  spherical.phi = 0;
  spherical.makeSafe(); // important thing, see the docs for what it does
  endPos.setFromSpherical(spherical);
  
  startPos.copy(camera.position);
  
  tri.set(endPos, scene.position, startPos);
  tri.getNormal(axis);
  
  let angle = startPos.angleTo(endPos);
  
  let value = {value: 0};
  gsap.to(value, {value: 1, 
    duration: 2,
    onUpdate: function(){
      camera.position.copy(startPos).applyAxisAngle(axis, angle * value.value);
      controls.update();
    },
    onStart: function(){
      moveUp.disabled = true;
    },
    onComplete: function(){
      moveUp.disabled = false;
    }
    })
    .play();/**/
}

renderer.setAnimationLoop(()=>{
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
});
</script>
```

Answer (score -2):

The better way to smoothly translate a camera would be to create keyframes and position them in some form of timeline defined by a emphasys curve.